how to disable read notifications in whatsapp cloud api
my webhook is flooded with lot of read notifications from whatsapp cloud api v20.0. I want to disable receiving read and delivered notifications for my webhook. how to do this?
sample read notification.
{"object":"whatsapp_business_account","entry":[{"id":"xxx","changes":[{"value":{"messaging_product":"whatsapp","metadata":{"display_phone_number":"xxx","phone_number_id":"xxx"},"statuses":[{"id":"wamid.xxx","status":"read","timestamp":"1725094296","recipient_id":"xxx"}]},"field":"messages"}]}]}
im already using logic inside my webhook handler to skip read notifications. I want to configure meta cloud-api itself to stop sending me read notifications.

Facebook doesn't typically give this much granular control over the webhooks. You may need to receive and ignore them.

but this control was available in on-premise api. I couldn't find any docs mentioning the same for cloud api.

For disabling the notifications, you will need to configure the webhook to allow filtering the specific type of notification that are more of a disturbance.
{
  "object": "whatsapp_business_account",
  "entry": [
    {
      "id": "xxx",
      "changes": [
        {
          "value": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "metadata": {
              "display_phone_number": "xxx",
              "phone_number_id": "xxx"
            },
            "statuses": [
              {
                "id": "wamid.xxx",
                "status": "read",
                "timestamp": "1725094296",
                "recipient_id": "xxx"
              }
            ]
          },
          "field": "messages"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Now in the webhook ignore notifications for "read" and "delivered"
// psudo code
import org.json.JSONArray; 
import org.json.JSONObject; 
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 

public class WebhookHandler { 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
 
 // Simulate getting the incoming request data (this would typically come from an HTTP POST request) 
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 StringBuilder jsonStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
 String line; 
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
  jsonStringBuilder.append(line); 
 } 
 
 // Convert the incoming JSON string to a JSONObject 
 String jsonString = jsonStringBuilder.toString(); 
 JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonString); 
 // Check if the notification is a status update 

 if (data.has("entry")) { 
  JSONArray entryArray = data.getJSONArray("entry"); 
  JSONObject entry = entryArray.getJSONObject(0); 
  if (entry.has("changes")) { 
   JSONArray changesArray = entry.getJSONArray("changes"); 
   JSONObject change = changesArray.getJSONObject(0); 
   JSONObject value = change.getJSONObject("value"); 
   if (value.has("statuses")) { 
    JSONArray statusesArray = value.getJSONArray("statuses"); 
    for (int i = 0; i < statusesArray.length(); i++) { 
     JSONObject status = statusesArray.getJSONObject(i); 
     String statusType = status.getString("status"); 
     // Check if the status is 'read' or 'delivered' 
     if ("read".equals(statusType) || "delivered".equals(statusType)) { 
      // Skip processing this notification 
      continue; 
     }  
     // Process other statuses (e.g., 'sent', 'failed', etc.) 

     processStatus(status); } } } } 

    // Continue with your webhook processing for other notifications 
} 

private static void processStatus(JSONObject status) { 
// Your code to handle the status (e.g., 'sent', 'failed', etc.)
 System.out.println("Processing status: " + status); 
} }



this does not answer my question of how to disable to read notifications hitting my webhook itself. I'm  already using the same logic ignoring the read status update and processing only the message notifications alone.
